# Using NPRuntime plugin in Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, npruntime

I have successfully run NPRuntime plugin on webpage by copying it to firefox plugin directory. I want to create a firefox extension using it, so I created small extension that displays a textbox and a button on status bar, button click calls a javascript function which takes value from textbox and passes as a argument to the function in NpRuntime plugin which is embeded in XUL.

But when I try to call the function I get Javascript exception as that variable is null.

```
try{
var myplugin=document.getElementById("myplugin");
myplugin.test(document.getElementById("txtUri").value);// calling function
}catch(e){
alert(e.message); //throws the error as myplugin is null
}
```

**When I remove function call there is no error** so embed tag getting recognized by javascript. I kept a plugin dll in firefox plugins directory. **I also tried creating a plugins directory under extension root and keeping my dll in that but it did not succeed** .

Please help me get going,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "which is embeded in XUL"

How? I bet you use <embed> in the XUL namespace, which doesn't have any special meaning.

You should [define the HTML namespace and use the embed tag in the html namespace](http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/html.html).

> When I remove function call there is no error so embed tag getting recognized by javascript.

This is wrong. If you remove the function call, there's no code left to fail -- getElementById never throws (at least not in such simple cases). This doesn't indicate your XUL code is fine.

> I also tried creating a plugins directory under extension root and keeping my dll in that but it did not succeed .

That is [definitely supposed to work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Bundles). Can you put an XPI that demonstrates the problem somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Calling NPAPI plugins from Firefox extensions is tricky.  One option, which seems like a bit of a hack, is to actually inject the plugin into the DOM which represents the browser UI.

A better option is to modify the DOM of pages as they are loaded in to the browser:

[Scriptable NPAPI plugin doesn't work with Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688904/scriptable-npapi-plugin-doesnt-work-with-firefox)

Or you can skip the NPAPI plugin altogether, and use js-ctypes:

[Using a plugin generated with Firebreath in a Firefox Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208940/using-a-plugin-generated-with-firebreath-in-a-firefox-extension/7572615#7572615)