# Load firebreath plugin in Firefox extension without injecting anything in DOM

Tags: plugins, firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath

Is there any way to load firebreath plugin in firefox extension.I've seen one way by injecting html related to plugin into DOM as explain here(see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688904/scriptable-npapi-plugin-doesnt-work-with-firefox")
I think its better that extension will load plugin in background to avoid any security issues.
my plugin has nothing to do with drawing, its just send data to a specific port by calling a simple function.I'm new to extension development so any example will be helpful...

Comment: Fixed it by loading it in XUL file

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you figured it out, but for the sake of any who find this question with the same issue: a NPAPI-based plugin (FireBreath or otherwise) can only be loaded inside of a DOM; however, in the case of a firefox extension (or Chrome extension for that matter) it doesn't have to neccesarily be the DOM of the web page, it could also be the DOM of the extension.

In this case, you can load the plugin in the XUL file.

It's also worth checking out this thread:

[Using a plugin generated with Firebreath in a Firefox Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208940/using-a-plugin-generated-with-firebreath-in-a-firefox-extension/7572615#7572615)